# Sonar 4.2 - PMD 2.1 throwing exception

Tags: plugins, null, pmd, sonarqube

I have downloaded the PMD 2.1 plugin and when I activate the rules from it, my analysis failes with the following error:

org.jdom.IllegalDataException: The data "null" is not legal for a JDOM attribute: A null is not a legal XML value.

If I disable the rules my analysis will work without error.  Has anyone solved this riddle?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [a known bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3644) that is still unresolved.
On the linked page, you can vote for the issue to get it fixed faster.

**Update:** The bug was fixed on May 5th, 2014, and scheduled for the 2.2 release of the plugin.